# Wrong results when using Join in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am trying to get data through `find()`

This is my code:

```
 $query = Users::find()->where("is_deleted = '0'")->join('INNER JOIN', 'roles', 'users.role = roles.id')->join('INNER JOIN', 'email_list' , 'users.email = email_list.id')->select('users.name , users.user_name , email_list.email ,roles.name role');
```

And all I got in email field is `0`.

I tested the DB and there is true emails.

The grid code:

```
GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
//'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'columns' => [
['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
'name',
'user_name',
'email:email',
'role',
['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
],
]);
```

Why is this ? How to fix it ?

Comment: What SQL statement does your code produce in the debug system?

Answer (score 3):

You are using ActiveRecord but you join are not as ActiveRecord shouold be. Create relations in models for each join:

```
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Role::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getEmailLists()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EmailList::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

And use it like:

```
Users::find()->joinWith(['roles', 'email_list']);
```